# Get specific row of datatable

Tags: c#

I have a big datatable like this:

[image]

Query for this list is:

```
var currentDesignKey = (from DataRow dr in designFolioList.Rows select (int)dr["DesignKey"]).FirstOrDefault()
```

As you can see I have a `FirstOrDefault()` which always get DataRow `[0]` of table, I want to know how can I get specific table something like:

```
(from DataRow dr in designFolioList.Rows select (int)dr["DesignKey"])[11]
```

How can I achieve that? Regards

Comment: Is there a criteria?  Or do you just want the 12th row?

Comment: I jus want 12th row @LarsTech

Comment: Skip(11) and Take(1) might help

Answer (score 2):

You can access a specific `DataRow` in the `Rows` collection directly by indexer.

```
var key = (int)designFolioList.Rows[11]["DesignKey"];
```

will retrieve the 12th row's DesignKey column value and cast it to an Int32.

You would do well to actually check that there are enough rows in the table before trying direct index access, otherwise you may get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.